# Windows shortcut doesn't work: how to enclose filenames with spaces?

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts

Here's my problem: I've made a shortcut on my Desktop (Windows XP (sigh)) like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k "mysql -u root drupal-defaultadm < ^"C:\Documents and Settings\AAA\Mes documents\Downloads\01.drupal-defaultadm.sql^" && exit"
```

When I double click on it, the DOS prompt is opened, but I get this error:

```
File not found.
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin>
```

So I'm trying to do the command "by hand" and only removing the `^`:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin>mysql -u root drupal-defaultadm < "C:\Documents and Settings\AAA\Mes documents\Downloads\01.drupal-defaultadm.sql"
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin>
```

And gives no error. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the whitespaces enclosed with `"`.

How shall I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just have the shortcut as

```
C:\whatever\path\mysql -u root drupal-defaultadm < "C:\Documents and Settings\AAA\Mes documents\Downloads\01.drupal-defaultadm.sql"
```

and you could use cmd.exe as well like this

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:\whatever\path\mysql -u root drupal-defaultadm < "C:\Documents and Settings\AAA\Mes documents\Downloads\01.drupal-defaultadm.sql"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I want the window to close (= add **`&& exit`**) or execute another program via **`&& something else`** your solution doesn't work... And I want that windows to close as soon as it's finished.

Comment: For that use the second version with flag /C. The command prompt would close after executing the command.

Comment: With `/C` it works, than you